# Fetch counts of different sets of Status IDs from same table in single query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

**Here is the query below. Please suggest how can I simplify the same:**

*In the query, I have to select counts of email generations with specified Submission Status IDs. As you can see, I have to fetch counts from same table still I have to provide separate query for different Submission Status sets.*

```
SELECT  a.id, a.created_at, a.recruiter_id,
           CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) as f_name,

(select count(*) from email_generations where email_generations.candidate_id = a.id and
 email_generations.submission_status_id = 2) as subm_count,

SUM((select count(*) from submission_statuses where submission_statuses.id IN (7,8) and submission_statuses.id =
 email_generations.submission_status_id)) as phn_intw_count,

SUM((select count(*) from submission_statuses where submission_statuses.id IN (9,10) and submission_statuses.id =
 email_generations.submission_status_id)) as intw_count,

SUM((select count(*) from submission_statuses where submission_statuses.id IN (12,13) and submission_statuses.id =
 email_generations.submission_status_id)) as offer_count,

SUM((select count(*) from submission_statuses where submission_statuses.id IN (11) and submission_statuses.id =
 email_generations.submission_status_id)) as ref_chk_count

FROM candidates AS a

INNER JOIN email_generations ON email_generations.candidate_id = a.id WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL

GROUP BY a.id HAVING a.recruiter_id = 1 and (subm_count <> 0 OR phn_intw_count <> 0 OR intw_count <> 0 OR offer_count <> 0 OR
 ref_chk_count <> 0)
```

Table: [Email Generation Table Structure,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHlLW.png)
[Submission Statuses Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtR0b.png)

**DESIRED OUTPUT should be something like below example - **

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
 <colgroup span="2" width="85">
 </colgroup>
 <colgroup width="174">
 </colgroup>
 <colgroup width="85">
 </colgroup>
 <colgroup width="110">
 </colgroup>
 <colgroup span="2" width="85">
 </colgroup>
 <colgroup width="92">
 </colgroup>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" height="17"><b>Candidate ID</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>Recruiter ID</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>Candidate Name</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>subm_count</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>phn_intw_count</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>intw_count</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>offer_count</b></td>
   <td align="left"><b>ref_chk_count</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="right" height="17" sdnum="16393;" sdval="258">11258</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="1">1</td>
   <td align="left">Test Candidate</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="0">4</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="0">2</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="0">9</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="1">1</td>
   <td align="right" sdnum="16393;" sdval="0">3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Post your table structures to

Comment: table structure with your current active record query

Comment: @MayankPandeyz : Please refer table structure images below. Thanks in advance

Comment: @TusharPal : Please refer table structure images below. I am using raw query rather than active record query. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post it as answer, post it in your question

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @max The above query is working fine. But it is not optimised. I am looking for if it can be optimised.

Comment: @RudrakshiSrivastava might be way off here but if you're using Rails and you want a count of email generations for each candidate by status_id having a specific recruiter_id of 1 you could do something like `EmailGeneration.joins(:candidate).where(recruiter_id: 1).group('candidates.id', 'email_generations.submission_status_id').count` which would return something like `{[candidates.id, email_generations.submission_status_id] => count, [candidates.id, email_generations.submission_status_id] => count, etc...}`

Comment: @user3366016 Please refer the table structure for desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends for your quality time. I have optimised the query myself and would like to share it with you all.

Thanks to @user3366016 for the hint to fetch records from Email Generation rather than Candidate.

> SELECT DISTINCT candidates.id, candidates.created_at,
>   candidates.recruiter_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', candidates.first_name,
>   candidates.middle_name, candidates.last_name) as f_name,
>
> (select count(*) FROM email_generations AS e WHERE e.submission_status_id = 2 and e.candidate_id = candidates.id) AS
>   subm_count,
>
> (select count(*) FROM email_generations AS e WHERE e.submission_status_id IN (7,8) and e.candidate_id = candidates.id) AS
>   phn_intw_count,
>
> (select count(*) FROM email_generations AS e WHERE e.submission_status_id IN (9,10) and e.candidate_id = candidates.id)
>   AS intw_count,
>
> (select count(*) FROM email_generations AS e WHERE e.submission_status_id IN (12,13) and e.candidate_id = candidates.id)
>   AS offer_count,
>
> (select count(*) FROM email_generations AS e WHERE e.submission_status_id IN (11) and e.candidate_id = candidates.id) AS
>   ref_chk_count
>
> FROM email_generations
>
> INNER JOIN candidates ON candidates.id = email_generations.candidate_id AND candidates.deleted_at IS NULL
>
> WHERE email_generations.deleted_at IS NULL AND (candidates.recruiter_id = 1 and
>   email_generations.submission_status_id IN (2,7,8,9,10,12,13,11))
>
> HAVING (subm_count <> 0 OR phn_intw_count <> 0 OR intw_count <> 0 OR offer_count <> 0 OR ref_chk_count <>0)